# Where does the square root of two in the conversion between the Fermi constant and the weak coupling constant come from?

Tags: standard-model, physical-constants, weak-interaction

As in the title, where does the square root of two in the conversion

$$
G_{F}=\frac{\sqrt{2}g^{2}}{8m_{W}^{2}}
$$

between the Fermi constant and the weak coupling constant come from? I was able to derive from the effective quark/lepton coupling in the SM (i.e. integrating out the W boson field) each factor in the above equation, apart from the square root.

EDIT: Please, restrain from answering with something like "it is a convention". Conventions are introduced for specific reasons, you don't introduce awkward factors of $\sqrt{2}$ just for fun. So, should it be a convention, I'd also like to know its motivation.

Comment: I'm afraid it seems to be indeed just a convention to write the Lagrangian of Fermi theory as something like $\frac{G_F}{\sqrt{2}} J_\mu J^{\mu\dagger}$. You might also notice that e.g. the muon half-life has pretty horrible numerical factors in it when written in terms of $G_F$ and $m_\mu$. I'm not sure you should expect a good reason for this.

Comment: In this case the factor of $\sqrt{2}$ makes the term look worse rather than better. They could have defined $G_{F}$ to be $g^{2}/4m_{W}^{2}$ or $g^{2}/8m_{W}^{2}$,  the term would then be $\frac{G_{F}}{2} J^{\mu}J^{\dagger}_{\mu}$ or $G_{F}J^{\mu}J^{\dagger}_{\mu}$, and both are better looking, so I guess there is some other reason. One $\sqrt{2}$ appears in the relation between the Higgs vacuum and $G_{F}$, $v=(\sqrt{2}G_{F})^{-1/2}$, but since the concept was not introduced until 1964 it seems anachronistic to me.

Comment: Again, I'm ok with the $\sqrt{2}$ being a convention, as far as I'm given its motivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fermi defined the theory back when the Neutrino was thought to spin both ways. That means it ends up with double the number of outgoing states as in nature. The original Fermi constant was measured by fitting Fermi's two-way-spinning-neutrino theory to Neutron decay, and wrongly made the phase space for the outgoing neutrino twice too big. The square of $G_F$ appears in emission probabilities, the experimental lifetime of the neutron didn't change when the theory was fixed, so the effective constant needed to be $\sqrt{2}$ times bigger to still match.